# Custom Rating Bar show one star only

Tags: android

[image].

I create a custom rating bar. I set 5 custom star images, but it shows only one. Instead of a variable number of rating drawables, I see only one, regardless of the number of stars set. Any help will be appreciated.

**xml.code :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical">

<RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/ratingbar_default"
    style="@style/RatingBar"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="276dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="show state up checkbox"
    android:textColor="#CC00CC"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
```

**java code :**

```
Activity RatingBarActivity

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_rating);

            final TextView text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);

            final RatingBar ratingBar_default = (RatingBar) findViewById(R.id.ratingbar_default);

            ratingBar_default.setOnRatingBarChangeListener(new RatingBar.OnRatingBarChangeListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onRatingChanged(RatingBar ratingBar, float rating, boolean fromUser)
                        {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            text.setText("Rating: " +         String.valueOf(rating));
                        }
                });

 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item
    android:id="@android:id/background"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_empty" />
<item
    android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_empty" />
<item
    android:id="@android:id/progress"
    android:drawable="@drawable/star_ratingbar_full_filled" />
</layer-list>
```

**res/drawable/star_ratingbar_full_empty.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/star2" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/star2" />

 <item android:state_selected="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/star2" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/star2" />

</selector>
```

**res/drawabstar_ratingbar_full_filled.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<!-- This is the rating bar drawable that is used to
show a unfilled cookie. -->
<selector
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_pressed="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/star3" />

<item android:state_focused="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/star1" />

<item android:state_selected="true"
  android:state_window_focused="true"
  android:drawable="@drawable/star1" />

<item android:drawable="@drawable/star1" />

</selector>
```

**styles.xml file :**

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar"></style>

<style name="RatingBar" parent="@android:style/Widget.RatingBar">
    <item     name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/star_rating_bar_full</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:maxHeight">48dip</item>
</style>

</resources>
```

Comment: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30753688/android-ratingbar-below-lollipop-renders-incorrectly/

Answer (score 46):

In my case trouble was in SVG drawables in layer-list. When I changed them to PNG it starts work correctly

Comment: Same issue in my case too. But what if want to use only svgs?

Comment: @Pinkesh Darji If new support libs still reproduce this case, only way is to go with old school cut

Answer (score 2):

Try to specify an `android:numStars` attribute for your RatingBar in layout file `activity_rating.xml`. I guess, the default value is 1 - that's why you see only one star

Comment: Cool soft i have already tried this   <RatingBar

                        android:numStars="5"
                        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/ratingbar_selector"
                        android:stepSize="0.2" />

Comment: The green star on your screenshot seems to be a full_empty star from layer @android:id/background. Does it respond to taps?
I also took a look at @drawable/ratingbar_full_holo_dark and found that it doesn't use selectors. Does your code display all the stars if your use static images instead of selectors? The Holo ratingbar also re-defines indeterminateDrawable (along with progressDrawable). I suppose you need to define it too.

Comment: This is not at all an answer to this question. We already tried with numStars=5

Answer (score 1):

Just remove `any-dpi` drawable of rating bar filled and empty image from drawable. And it will work for you. Because it to show custom rating bar you can give both `xml` and png files in your `layer list`. But to show all the stars, you have to put only `png` icons into `drawable` folder.

Answer (score -2):

Has been a while but never hurts to answer.
Here is my 3 step solution regardless of SDK version.

1- Add this as your RatingBar in your xml layout:

```
    <RatingBar
    android:id="@+id/new_ratingbar"
    android:progressDrawable="@drawable/custom_drawable" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:numStars="5"
    android:stepSize="0.5"/>
```

If needed, you can give the RatingBar minHeight and maxHeight or add other attributes as required.

2- Here is the drawable you would refer the above android:progressDrawable to:

**custom_drawable.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/background"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_empty" /> <!--this is your .png file-->
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/secondaryProgress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_fill" /> <!--this is your .png file-->
    <item
        android:id="@android:id/progress"
        android:drawable="@drawable/rating_bar_fill" /> <!--this is your .png file-->
</layer-list>
```

3- The last thing is to provide the .png files in your various drawable folders.